# FFMPEG Concat result audio delay

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, concatenation, delay

I am editing some old homemade videos and I would like to split the files (~2h long, 60 GB) to smaller chunks ~10-15 min long for archiving on different media.

Currently I am testing merge/concatenate of the files (segments) back to the full length video (source).

Source files are interlaced, constant 25 fps, lossless ff1v 3.4, yuv 4:2:2 with pcm_s16le 48kHz audio. I generate splitted files with demuxer “segment” with the following command:

```
ffmpeg -r 25 -i source.mkv" -force_key_frames "expr:gte(t,n_forced*60)" -map 0 ^
-c:v copy -c:a pcm_s16le -f segment -segment_time 00:01:00 ^
-segment_time_delta 0 -reset_timestamps 1 -break_non_keyframes 0 ^
"%%~out_part%%03d.mkv"
```

<sub>(-r, -force_key_frames can be omitted - result is the same)</sub>

Then I use VirtualDub2 to compare number of frames, frames at split positions and audio: the command generates segments which are identical to the source (frame numbers, audio delay etc.). So, this step seems to be OK.

With the concat command I concatenate these splatted files (segments):

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i list.txt -c copy D:\output.mkv
```

When comparing (VirtualDub2) the result of concat with the source I noticed that the result has a delayed audio (video frames are ok) - see image bellow.

Now, this is not a deal braker, since the delay is about 10 ms per segment, but I am still wondering if I am doing sth wrong.

It seems that delay is compounding: concat of 1 minute segments will generate more delay than concat of 5 min segments.

[IMAGE of source vs Concat result (and segment), audio delay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4B8nf.png)

With ffprobe (-show_format -show_streams) on segments I noticed that the audio stream has a property “start_time=0.001000”, could this be a problem?

I ran “-f md5” hash and “-framehash -hash md5” on source and concat result but the hashes are equal. It could be VirtualDub2 itself…

Are there any parameters for concat or perhaps segment that can be used to mitigate this behavior?

Any suggestions are welcome.

Best Regards!

---

Info on source file:

```
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'source.mkv':
  Metadata:
    ENCODER         : Lavf58.29.100
  Duration: 00:34:47.16, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 64117 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: ffv1 (FFV1 / 0x31564646), yuv422p(bt470bg), 768x576, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      ENCODER         : Lavc58.54.100 ffv1
      DURATION        : 00:34:47.040000000
    Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_s16le, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1536 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      DURATION        : 00:34:47.161000000
```

Answer (score 2):

As it turns out using concat in the way described above leads to audio issues.
Alternative is to generate .m3u8 file (segment list) with options copyts and start_at_zero. Additionally one should extract audio to separate file as a whole (not segmented).

Command for segmenting a file:

```
ffmpeg -i "source.mkv" -dn -sn ^
    -c:v copy -c:a copy -copyts -start_at_zero ^
    -f segment -segment_list "out.m3u8" -segment_time 00:05:00 "out_part%%03d.mkv" ^
    -dn -sn -vn -c:a copy "out.wav"
```

This should generate m3u8 file, video+audio segments and audio file in wav.

Concatenation: instead of using concat, we open the m3u8 playlist and audio file and merge segments with command:

```
ffmpeg -i "source.m3u8" ^
    -i "source.wav" ^
    -map 0:0 -map 1:0 ^
    -c:v copy -c:a copy "out_merged.mkv"
```

With command map we map appropriate streams to out_merged file.
In my limited testing the audio was ok even if I omitted generating separate audio file (and just merge audio in segments) but it seems to me this is better practice for archiving.

I am not knowledgeable enough in ffmpeg to know the difference with this approach and using concat like in OP (sth on killing timestamps maybe?). I got similar code and "inspiration" from the following answer: https://superuser.com/a/1536037/1147027 . It mentions distinction between "segment list file" and "concat file".

So big thanks to Eugen Rieck.

---

To add:
On some files there was a 1/4 of a frame audio delay but it seems that it was not compounding over the length of the video (2h) or due to shortening segment duration (1 min segments vs 5 min segments), like it does in the case with concat in OP. This was true while merging segmented audio or audio in a separate file.

The merged file is somewhat smaller than the source (~700 B on 30 GB video) but md5 hash of audio/video is the same.

The interesting thing is that if the merged file is segmented and merged again (source > segment -> merge > segment2 > merge2) there is no audio delay in merge2 vs merge (even if there was in source vs merge) and the files are the same size. md5 hash stays the same.

Moreover I tested segmentation and concatenation on generated video+audio clip. It represents some simple colors and sine wave audio with added "beeps" for easy detection of anomalies between segments:

```
ffmpeg -v "verbose" ^
    -f lavfi -i color=white:640x480:d=720 ^
    -f lavfi -i color=red:640x480:d=900 ^
    -f lavfi -i color=blue:640x480:d=420 ^
    -f lavfi -i "sine=f=25:b=100:r=48000:d=2040" ^
    -filter_complex "[0][1][2]concat=n=3:v=1:a=0,format=yuv420p[v0]" ^
    -map "[v0]" -map 3:a -shortest ^
    -c:v ffv1 -c:a pcm_s16le sample_source.mkv
```