# Video scaling in ffmpeg causes audio gaps

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I am trying to scale down a video (mp4 format) by using the following process :

1. Segment the video

```
ffmpeg -v quiet -i <input-file> -map 0 -c copy -f segment -segment_time <segment_length> -reset_timestamps 1 -avoid_negative_ts make_non_negative output_%03d.mp4
```

2. Scale down each segment parallelly

```
ls output_*.mp4 |  parallel ffmpeg -v quiet -i {} -vf scale=-2:<output-resolution> temp_{#}.mp4
```

3. Join segments to get back whole video

```
for i in temp_*.mp4; do echo file "$i"; done > concat.txt
ffmpeg -v quiet -f concat -i concat.txt -codec copy <output-file>
```

However, the final output contains small audio gaps. Consider segment length of 15s, then at roughly 15.28s there is a gap in the audio stream as shown in the waveform of audio below.

[image: Audio waveform]

The green part highlights the waveform of the audio generated by scaling down the video using this command :

```
ffmpeg -v quiet -i <input-file> -vf scale=-2:<output-resolution> <output-file>
```

The yellow part highlights the waveform of the audio scaled down using the segmenting process described earlier.

One approach I could think of is to work on the video stream only while segmenting and copy the audio stream from the input file directly to the output file. But again it might lead to audio sync issues. How do I solve this ?

I am using ffmpeg version git-2020-03-03-60b1f85 in Windows 10.

*Please note that I don't want to re-encode the video because this will defeat the purpose of segmenting in the first place (in terms of time taken).*

Answer (score 1):

It is not the video scaling, that produces the gaps, but it is the process of splitting and joining while killing the timestamps.

This is quite a usual problem in the broadcast industry, and we typically solve it this way:

- split audio and video, in the process using the `hls` segmenter **with a segment list file**
- do parallel video processing of the segemnts **without changes to the timestamps** and audio processing i/a
- rejoin audio and video by pointing ffmpeg to **the segment list file**, not a concat file

**EXAMPLES**

Split:

```
ffmpeg -y -i ... -dn -sn -an -c:v copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -copyts -start_at_zero -f segment -segment_list /path/to/output.m3u8 -segment_time 30 /path/to/folder/para%05d.ts -dn -sn -vn -c:a copy /path/to/audiofile
```

Rejoin:

```
ffmpeg -y -i /path/to/output.m3u8 -i /path/to/audiofile -map '0:v' -map '1:a' -c:a copy -c:v copy /path/to/output.mp4
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, What is i/a in the second point?

Comment: If possible please provide an example, it will be very helpful

Comment: i/a is "if applicable" ... if you just copy the audio it is nothing, but if you need to e.g. recompress or normalize  audio you can do it inparallel to the video processing.

Comment: The rejoin command gives an error : `Invalid stream specifier: '0:v'`. If I remove the map options, it executes but says `Packet corrupt` when reading each ts file

Comment: That seams to be a bug in your version of ffmpeg, I copy-pasted the line from our own reencode servers (and I would know **immediately** if they wouldn't work). Since only one of the streams contains a video stream and only one an audio stream, the `-map` parameters are not strictly necessary.

Comment: Is there any particular reason to use this `-bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb` ? While processing I found that with or without the this option the output file remained the same (sha256 generated for the files was same)

Comment: Also how will the output change if I use a segment list of type `ffconcat` (segments in mp4 format) when compared to segment list of type `m3u8` (segments in ts format) ? I expected both outputs to be same irrespective of the formats since there is no re-encoding involved, but I was wrong, there are changes to stream parameters like `tbn`,`bitrate`

Comment: `ffconcat` files are not segement lists, they are movie lists. This makes a huge difference with timestamps - which is why the audio dropouts appear.

Comment: the `-bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb` is auto-inserted by ffmpeg if not given, but since this is not 100% foolproof, we tend to put it in manually - same as why we have the `map` that are not strictly necessary.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I have one more question, In between the split and rejoin process I will be scaling the video but the output file obtained during the scaling process will be a different ts file (name), which will cause a problem during rejoin process as the m3u8 file contains the ts file names as per split command, any suggestions on how do to deal with this ?

Comment: Just use a script (batch file) to rename the segments or edit the m3u8 file to reflect the new names.

Comment: Sorry, I don't do 1:1 chat

Comment: ok, but I am curious about this, the quality of the video has reduced in terms of bitrate, for ex: using the concat method I got a bitrate of 837kb/s and the video stream had this output `Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x360, 705 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)` as per ffmpeg, but using the hls segment method i am now getting bitrate of 667kb/s with the video params as `Video: mpeg2video (Main) (mp4v / 0x7634706D), yuv420p(tv), 640x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 537 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc (default)
` Is this expected ?How can I retain the quality?

Comment: The Quality of the video (indeed the bit-by-bit content of the video) isnot changed by split/rejoin. It might be changed in your interim processing, though

Comment: Yes, in the intermediate process (scaling) the encoder was set to `mpeg2video` by default since `.ts` files are being scaled, probably by doing this `-codec h264 `  I can retain the quality

Comment: This is a completly different question: "How do I transcode .ts files in h.264". You would go along the lines of `-c:v x264` or just directly use the `x264` uitility.